# Forgot to get gas

Tags: money, automobiles

I prepaid for gas and forgot to pump it but immediately returned to tell the cashier. But he would not return my money or let me get the gas. what should I do? This happened in Berwick Pennsylvania USA at a Sunoco  gas station.

Comment: Try as I might I can't think of a way that I could forget to pump the gas...it is usually just two steps with nothing in between: pay and pump, or pump and pay. Maybe that's why the cashier was sceptical.

Comment: Did you actually go inside and pay for the gas in advance? Or did you set a pay limit at the pump and then leave before pumping?

Comment: It's not clear to me that this is anything to do with travel.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not related to travel

Answer (score 3):

Ask to speak with the manager, show your receipt, ask them to check the cameras, most likely the credit is still in their computer system.

Answer (score 1):

If immediately you meant, by left and came back, there is a chance that you just gave someone free gas. If you haven't left yet or no one has used the pump, the credit will still be there and you are still entitled to either your money or your gas. If someone pumped it, it's really up to the store, It is up for debate, because it could be construed as you prepaying for someone else, or being generous (in the ex.: paying for the next person in line). Gas stations are usually owned by a single person and they don't make much, talk to them and don't be a jerk. They don't make much money off of gas.

Comment: If you left and nobody used your credit, then the pump will not have charged your card.